# How does Spring automatically converts Java Objects and Array Lists into JSON automatically?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm wondering how does Spring automatically converts Java objects and ArrayLists automatically to JSON without any dependencies. (My project does not have any libraries  like GSON.)The below code returns a JSON arraylist!

```
package com.damian.springwebmvc.controllers;

import com.damian.springwebmvc.dto.Customer_DTO;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/json")
public class JSONHandler {
    public JSONHandler() {
        System.out.println("JSONHandler instantiated via constructor!");
    }

   

    @GetMapping
    public List<Customer_DTO> getJSON() {
        ArrayList<Customer_DTO> customer_dtos = new ArrayList<>();
        customer_dtos.add(new Customer_DTO("THIS IS A RESPONSE", "THIS IS A RESPONSE.", "THIS IS A RESPONSE.", 0.0));
        customer_dtos.add(new Customer_DTO("THIS IS A RESPONSE", "THIS IS A RESPONSE.", "THIS IS A RESPONSE.", 0.0));
        customer_dtos.add(new Customer_DTO("THIS IS A RESPONSE", "THIS IS A RESPONSE.", "THIS IS A RESPONSE.", 0.0));
        customer_dtos.add(new Customer_DTO("THIS IS A RESPONSE", "THIS IS A RESPONSE.", "THIS IS A RESPONSE.", 0.0));
        return customer_dtos;
    }
}
```

Below is my Spring dependecy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Spring pulls in a ton of transitive dependencies. One of them is a JSON serializer. I think it's Jackson by default.

Comment: Chances are that the numerous dependencies of "spring-webmvc", include some JSON stuff, e.g the jackson dependencies . Try to display the full dependency tree of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring itself has some dependencies. And when you send Json as an input to your Controller Spring will attempt to convert your Json into instance of a class that is a parameter of your method in your controller that is behind that particular API. The same with return type - Spring will serialize your instance of a class that you return into JSON. Spring uses Json-Jackson library as default, but you can configure it to any other libraries. The most popular JSON libraries are [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (or also known as Faster XML) and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)